# Winforms version WPF ScaleTransform?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, zooming, scaletransform

I'm attempting to create something of a software zoom for an image in my Winforms application. I noticed an answer to a similar issue stating that it could be achieved with the mousewheel by using

```
private void image_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var st = (ScaleTransform)image.RenderTransform;
    double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
    st.ScaleX += zoom;
    st.ScaleY += zoom;
}
```

That solution is exactly what I need, but it appears to be part of System.Windows.Media, which doesn't seem to be part of the Winforms architecture.

Does anyone know of a similar option for Winforms that would end up resembling this functionality? My google searches haven't turned up much :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [`Graphics.ScaleTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx). The idea of arbitrary transformations as part of the rendering process isn't as all-pervasive in Windows Forms, but you could transform one image to another image via `Graphics`, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Noob question, though: I'm targeting .NET framework 4.5, but when I try to use System.Graphics, it can't find it >_> Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user1548103: Yes, you're trying to use a class from the `System.Drawing` namespace, but specifying it as if it were in the `System` namespace :)